# Unauthorized error while trying to add LetsEncrypt to a domain using Nginx with docker for Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, nginx, lets-encrypt

I am trying to add HTTPS to my domain using LetsEcnrypt. My server setup so far is, I have Spring Boot running on Tomcat in a docker container on `Port 8088` and I have Nginx server in front of the Tomcat container which is allowed to access `Port 80` and `Port 443`. 
Here are my configuration files

> nginx.conf

```
http{
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;


        location / {
             proxy_pass        http://blab:8088;
             proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
        }
        location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            root /var/www/certbot;
        }
}
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         blab.com;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/blab.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/blab.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
             proxy_pass        http://blab:8088;
             proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    }
}
}
events {  }
```

Dockerfile for creating a nginx container

> Dockerfile

```
# latest nginx
FROM nginx
# copy custom configuration file
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
# expose server port
EXPOSE 80
# start server
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I am generating a docker image for nginx like this `docker image build -t custom-nginx:latest .`

Then I have `docker-compose.yml` like this

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  nginx_server:
    image: custom-nginx
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    depends_on:
      - "blab"

  blab:
    image: joker/blab
    ports:
      - '8088:8088'
```

So nginx is listening to `Port 80` and `Port 443` and Spring Boot is running on `Port 8088`

I can access the site on http. DNS mapping is correctly done but when I try to issue a certificate using this command

```
docker run -it --rm --name certbot \
            -v "/data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt" \
            -v "/data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot" \
            certbot/certbot certonly
```

I get this error

```
Challenge failed for domain blab.com
http-01 challenge for blab.com
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: blab.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://blab.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/sdaglkoweg235362gnvoerg
   [my_ip]: "<html>\r\n<head><title>404 Not
   Found</title></head>\r\n<body>\r\n<center><h1>404 Not
   Found</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.17.8</ce"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

`blab.com` is a hypothetical site, not the original site.

This is my problem. Any help on this would be hugely appreciated. Thanks

Comment: In your nginx Dockerfile, you aren't exposing port 443. Please check.

Comment: I think it has to do with your document root directory. I can't remember from the top of my head, but there are parameters for the challenge file location certbot uses. I think this is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may need to add the following parameters when invoking the certbot:

```
docker run -it --rm --name certbot \
            -v "/data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt" \
            -v "/data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot" \
            certbot/certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/certbot
```

Comment: That was the one I was looking for in my comment earlier :D

Answer (score 0):

I've just noticed that you have relative source paths `in docker-compose.yaml`:

```
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
```

whereas when you launch certbot, you are using absolute paths:

```
            -v "/data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt" \
            -v "/data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot" \
```

In theory, if you run `touch /data/certbot/www/blah.txt` on the server host, you should be able to hit http://blab.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/blah.txt with `curl` or open it in your browser.

Comment: I created the file but it is giving me 404 not found, I think, this means that the volume is not properly mounted but what could be the solution

Comment: Try changing all volumes in `docker-compose.yaml` to:

```
    volumes:
      - /data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - /data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - /data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
```